# Adding Dynamic Series to Excel chart

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have following  table:

```
              Label_1          Labe1_2       ...      Label_n
DATE_1            1
DATE_2                             2               
...
DATE_n                                                 3
```

need to create a stacked bar chart based on the table above where the rows and col can be dynamic. I saw a few examples where dynamic rows can be handled and it works fine using offset.

I am very new to excel any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the Pivot charts to get over this hurdle! thanks Nick for trying.

Comment: Interesting, that you choose your own answer as the answer to your ?, and don't even give us much info on just what your answer was.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the same way you make dynamic range names. Rather than try and explain it myself, this link has all the info you need. http://www.decisionmodels.com/optspeedf.htm

Comment: Thanks Nick, but I want to basically add multiple series dynamically, offset and counta example above only gives me dynamics within a series.

Comment: @Shah sorry for the misunderstanding. You could do it VBA I suspect but not without.

Comment: I am slowly learning that it can be done with Pivot tables :) unfortunately i am populating excel using poi and it won''t help much with Pivots.. thanks though!

Comment: I may have a solution Shah if you are still interested? Let me know.